# ¿Como puedo saber el resultado de un query en PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy ejecutando una consulta SELECT de php para mysql, quiero imprimir el query de mi consulta por ejemplo:

```
public function getUsers($id_user)
    {   
        $conexion = new Connection();
        $pdo = $conexion->getConexion();
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_user = :id_user ");
        $statement->bindValue('id_user', $id_user);
        $statement->execute();
        
    }
```

Y en pantalla me imprima SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_user = 48 que es el resultado de mi select, hay alguna forma de saberlo?

Comment: Esta respuesta te puede valer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements